# Java (погода с Gismeteo)

Tags: java

```
package com.company;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc=
                null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.gismeteo.ru/weather-krasnodar-5136/").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Нет интернета");
        }
        Elements spans=doc.select("span [class=js_value tab-weather__value_l]");
        System.out.println(span.text());
    }
}
```

Не хочет работать код.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.company;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc=
                null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.gismeteo.ru/weather-krasnodar-5136/").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Нет интернета");
        }
        Elements spans=doc.select("span [class=js_value tab-weather__value_l]");
        Element span = spans.get(0);
        System.out.println(span.text());
    }
}
```

Не хватает строки с получением элементов. Вроде все работает.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.company;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc=
            null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.gismeteo.ru/weather-yekaterinburg-4517/").get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Нет интернета");
    }
    Elements spans=doc.select("span [class=js_value tab-weather__value_l]");
    Element span = spans.get(0);
    System.out.println(span.text())
```